# "Unknown toolset: vcunk" executing bootstrap.bat of boost library

Tags: visual-c++, boost

I have the following printout when executing bootstrap.bat of boost library.

```
Found with vswhere C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional 
### 
### "Unknown toolset: vcunk" 
### 
### You can specify the toolset as the argument, i.e.: 
### .\build.bat msvc 
### 
### Toolsets supported by this script are: borland, como, gcc, gcc-nocygwin, intel-win32, mingw, vc12, vc14, vc141, vc142 
  If you have Visual Studio 2017 installed you will need to either update 
  ### the Visual Studio 2017 installer or run from VS 2017 Command Prompt 
  ### as we where unable to detect your toolset installation. 
  ### 
Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
```

I'm using boost version 1.72.0 and in my PC VS 2019 and 2022 are present. This problem came out after installing VS2022. I assume that the problem is due to the fact that boost v1.72 cannot be used with vc143 VS toolset. My question is: is there a way to call bootstrap.bat so that a specific toolset, different from latest VS installed version, is used (in my case 142)?

I've found the possibility to add an option to b2.exe in order to se the toolset, but it's the second boost installation step after bootstrap.bat execution. Regarding bootstrap.bat parameters I've not found anything that works.

Comment: Can't you run bootstrap.bat in a Visual Studio 2019 x64 developer command prompt so it has all the settings for VS2019 enabled?

Comment: I have to execute bootstrap.bat from inside a powershell script, is it possible to execute it using VS2019 command prompt? If I run this PS I have the same error: & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
& "C:\Boost\bootstrap.bat"

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue and solved this problem by editing the `bootstrap.bat` file. I made the following changes in the `bootstrap.bat` file:

1. There was a call to `build.bat` in `bootstrap.bat` file. I specified the msvc version to be used in `build.bat` by changing `call .\build.bat` to `call .\build.bat msvc : 14.3`.
2. Added `IF "%1"=="vc143" SET TOOLSET=msvc : 14.3` statement in `bootstrap.bat` file where rest of the declarations are located (e.g., for `vc142`).

Finally, I executed `bootstrap.bat vc143` in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
My solution: I opened the
`tools/build/src/engine/vswhere_usability_wrapper.cmd` file
and commented the `REM Visual Studio Unknown Version, Beyond 2019` section (lines 20-31),
so it won't try to use an earlier version than 2019.